# How to get the list of contacts that clicked the link in the email

Tags: sendgrid

In order to track down the users through a purchase funnel, we need to get the IDs (or emails) of the contacts that clicked the link in the email, how to do that in Sendgrid?

Not possible to do that through UTM tags, since the campaign is targeted at existing users and they have their UTM tags assigned previously.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you should register for the [Event Webhook](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/event). With the Event Webhook, events, like [engagement events including link clicks](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/event#engagement-events), are batched and sent to a URL you provide so that you can process them.

You can use the user's email address that comes as part of the event object, or you can send [custom arguments](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/event#unique-arguments-and-custom-arguments) with the email when you send it in order to tie back to specific messages that you sent. I wrote a blog post on [how to track and record which email was opened in a Rails application](https://www.twilio.com/blog/track-email-status-ruby-on-rails-sendgrid) which might give you some insight into how this works.